# Can I use BrowserSync without local webpage-files? (proxy?)

Tags: proxy, extern, browser-sync

Hi I am new to BrowserSync and I'd like to know whether it is suitable for my use-case.

I'd like to synchronize (NON local) webpages to multiple devices/browsers. 
This means just using BrowserSync with any live web page (http://example.com) which resources are not on my machine.

I played around with the proxy function but did not get it to work... Don't know if it's just not possible or if I did something wrong...

Comment: What exactly did you do to try and get the proxy running. I would say the proxy option is the way to go here.

Comment: Was wondering if you got this to work? and how?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to start Browsersync from the command line:

`browser-sync start --proxy "example.com"`

That should do the trick. Make sure you have browser sync installed (globally)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I always tried. I thought I were missing some required options but now I figured out that the company proxy server was the problem. It's working fine in my home network.